# google_mobile_ads on iOS Performance

Tags: flutter, admob, google-mobile-ads

i know it is a common topic, but does anyone have experience with https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads and iOS?
I searched quite a bit, but so far did not find a solution on how to really improve it a bit.

I have an app, that sadly needs (not my choice, but the clients) quite a few ad banners.
Before we implemented them performance was great, but now with 4 banners in a CustomScrollView my application is perfectly fine on Android, but barely usable on iOS!

DId anyone of you manage to at least make it better?
In some threads I read, that there is a way of reducing the fps for platform views, but that this does not work anymore. (if I understood that correctly)

Any tipps or tricks are highly appreciated as I am in a bit of pickle right now

Comment: I'm facing the same problem right now, did you find any workaround to prevent those performance issues ?